# Electron + Typescript File Structure

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I have a problem to structure my `electron` project using `typescript`.
 Basically, I want my file structure to look like this:

```
+dist
    compiled .js files from .ts files 
 +src
   .ts files
 +gui
   html pages 
 +package.json
 +tsconfig.json
```

My **tsconfig.json** files is as follows:

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
```

and my package.json files is as follows:

```
"name": "electron_test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "tsc && electron ./dist/main.js",
    "pack": "electron-packager . sample --out=dist --arch=x64 --platform=win32 --electron-version=3.0.3 --overwrite --prune --ignore=dist"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^3.0.3",
    "electron-packager": "^12.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

The problem with these files is when `typescript` files are compiled, they are converted to `javascript` inside the `dist` file. Here I need to use `main.js` for my `electron` app to call within `html` pages. However when `Html` pages are not inside the `dist` file, if I run the app, `html` pages are not called. Somehow `main.js` and `html` pages should be inside the same directory.

Comment: (1) "Basically, I want my file structure to look like this:" --- compile to dist folder. (2) "The problem with these files is when typescript files are compiled, they are converted to javascript inside the dist file.". (1) and (2) contradict each other but you want both?

Comment: I didn't get quite what contradicts. I have my ts files inside the src folder, when you run "tsc" command they are compiled into js inside the dist folder.

Comment: Yes, and above you say that you want that structure. But when you run `tsc` this already happens. So what's the question?

Comment: **However when Html pages are not inside the dist file, if I run the app, html pages are not displayed. Somehow main.js and html pages should be inside the same directory.** this is my problem if you read carefully above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You probably want to move all source files to `src` directory. This is not required but this is how usually people structure projects.

   - src

     - controllers (or w/e you call it)

       - ts files
     - gui

       - html files
2. I would recommend to use webpack instead of raw tsc. You want to use [CopyWebpackPLugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin)

   ```
   const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

   plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {from: './src/gui', to: ''},
   ]),
   ```

If you still want to use tsc, you can copy files manually my using `cp` in package.json.

**package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
    "copyHtml": "cp ./src/gui ./dist",
    "build": "tsc && npm run copyHtml",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "tsc && npm run copyHtml && electron ./dist/main.js",
    "pack": "electron-packager . sample --out=dist --arch=x64 --platform=win32 --electron-version=3.0.3 --overwrite --prune --ignore=dist"
  },
```

You can also use [cpx](https://github.com/mysticatea/cpx) if you worry about crossOs support.

Anyway the point is that dist directory should contain all output files. And it's self-contained, meaning you can send this directory to anyway and he/she should be able to run your project w/o any other dependencies.

Comment: The above package.json is doing exactly what I wanted to do thanks, however i wanted to ask whethe or not this is a hacky way of doing this? I try to  keep my system as clean as possible but honestly speaking, I'm not advanced enough to tangle with webpack setup right now.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a year late to the party, but I hope I can still help others with my answer. Here's an alternative solution to the complex file structure of electron apps that I came up with myself. It's not as conventional, but to me it makes a lot more sense.

My project's directory structure is roughly as follows:

```
app/
|- index.html
|- index.js    (electron main script)
|- bundle.js   (generated via webpack)

build/
|- compiled ts -> js files

dist/
|- packaged executables

src/
|- all source files (in typescript)
```

Basically, I just put the electron main script into `app/` alongside `index.html`. This makes sense to me since `dist/` should be reserved for the *distributed* application delivered to the end user, and in the case of an electron app, we don't give the user access to `index.html` directly anyways. The build process then runs as follows:

- call `tsc` on `src/`, output into `build/`

  - done by setting `"outdir": "build"` in `tsconfig.json`, then running `npx tsc`
- call `webpack` on `build/`, bundle everything into a single `app/bundle.js`

  - done by setting `output: { filename: 'bundle.js', path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')}`, then running `webpack build/src/[entry point]`
- `index.html` loads `bundle.js` via a script element

  - done by adding `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`
- `main.js` renders `index.html` via electron

  - done by setting `"main": "app/main.js"` in `package.json`, then running `npx electron .`
- `electron-builder` packages `app/` into a single executable

  - done by `npx electron-builder`, with a corresponding config specified in `package.json`

Given how the build process runs, the directory structure makes a lot of sense to me. `src/` stores the typescript source files, `build/` stores the built javascript files, `app/` stores all the files for the electron renderer process, and `dist/` stores the packaged distributables.

Comment: I think the packaged executables should be in Build, not Dist. The transpiled version should be in Dist. I use Angular-Electron, but I have also done plain TS-Electron projects, as well. My executables always end up in Build. Here is a great template: https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron